# invalid code signing app submission

Tags: xcode, bundle, code-signing

Im trying to submit an app to the app store and Im getting the following error. Ive seen similar problems posted & 2 different solutions suggested but neither of them have solved the issue.

"Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. Specifically, value "42Q68FE326.*" for key "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" is not supported."

I've seen 2 different responses to this issue -- that it either relates to the iCloud being enabled or that it relates to there being as asterisk/wildcard in the app id.

I created a distribution profile that doesn't have the wildcard/asterisk in it -- but iCloud is still enabled. There doesn't seem to be a checkbox to disable it…?

In the Xcode project, I set the code signing identity to the non-asterisk/wildcard distribution profile -- although in the Xcode organizer under provision profiles, the earlier profiles are still there -- including an 'iOS Team Provisiong Profile' with a status of 'valid signing identity not found'.

Im not sure if Im getting this error because this profile is still there and I need to change something else within the Xcode settings -- or if the problem still exists in the distribution profile itself and it relates to either the iCloud setting or the asterisk that I originally set up the app id with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can anyone verify if the problem is solved in Xcode version 4.1, like is said in this post http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21529?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Apple messed things up yesterday. Just disable iCloud for your app and regenerate your certificates and everything should work!

Comment: Do you know how to disable iCloud? I dont see an option to do so -- its highlighted with a green light as enabled and there arent any options to disable it...

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the option wasnt there yesterday and now its back in the dev center...:) provisioning > app ids > actions > configure.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem...but don't see anything about iCloud in the dev center's provisioning section.